# Google Load Balancer www to non-www redirects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am having some difficulty with www to non-www redirects with google load balancer.

Currently I have HTTP -> https working no problems, however, I haven't really seen any recent docs on how this works.

I have the load balancer setup to run all URLs to App Engine A and anything on `/imagery/*` to go to App Engine B.

That is all working well, however, I can't seem to get the www to non-www stuff to work correctly.

I have tried to setup a new 'Host' redirect for [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to domain.com as per the attached
[image]

but i get

[image]

Any help on this one?

I don't want to have to create another app just to handle the redirect, surely it is a simple enough thing to do, I'm sure many want this.

Comment: and what is the response when you call directly `domain.com`?

Comment: response when going to domain.com is as per expected, it shows the website

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out it was 2 things.

1. Remove the https:// from the host redirect, and just have the naked domain, domain.com.
2. It doesn't happen right away, there is some timing involved.

I updated to remove the https:// from the host redirect, waited a few hours and all was good.  it is now working as expected