# Google Load Balancer www to non-www redirects (2022 October Version)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wanted to use Google Load balancer to do wwww to non-www redirects.

There is [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67189602/google-load-balancer-www-to-non-www-redirects) asking the exactly same question. I followed the step but it did not work.

In particular, I selected "**Prefix redirect**" and clicked "**Done**" and "**Update**". However, later when I clicked it again, it became back to "**Full path redirect**."

My question: Do I need to add anything in the "path value"? If so, what should I add there? Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a new HTTPS load balancer, You must and should [Enable](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#for_new_https_load_balancers) HTTP to HTTPS Redirect checkbox to create the redirect.
As per official doc, Path value field should be blank and Post enabled above, follow this [Redirect Doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#partial-http-lb) which guides you in redirecting the path perfectly.

Note : While adding redirect path  configurations you need to save and then click done and update.  As you are not saving This might be the reason you are getting a full path redirect option when you cross check.

Comment: The setup shown above in the screenshot is exaclty what I did, but it still changed back to "Full path redirect." I did click done and update. Yes, I checked the "Https redirect."

Comment: The Enable HTTP to HTTPS Redirect checkbox is only available while creating a new HTTPS load balancer. It is not available when editing an existing load balancer. I have tried it in my environment It's working fine. So can you try by creating a new LB for http to https redirect?